# pytorch dataset with 2 transformation train and validation

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, dataset, training-data

I would like to use 2 different transformation one for training and the second one for validation and test.
I mean to add some augmentation during the train process and validate/test without this augmentation.

What's the pytorch way to do so?

I mean to run 2 different transforms with torch.utils.data.Subset or torch.utils.data.Dataloader functions rather than creating 2 datasets.

Answer (score 2):

An example of separate train and test sets can be obtained through the `train` parameter when instantiating a data-set. Within this same constructor you can specify transforms, as shown [here](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/basics/data_tutorial.html) by the PyTorch team.

```
import torch
from torch.utils.data import Dataset
from torchvision import datasets
from torchvision.transforms import ToTensor
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


training_data = datasets.FashionMNIST(
    root="data",
    train=True,
    download=True,
    transform=ToTensor()
)

test_data = datasets.FashionMNIST(
    root="data",
    train=False,
    download=True,
    transform=ToTensor()
)
```

If you say wished to apply a random horizontal flip to input data, with probability 0.5, you could change `transform=ToTensor()` to `transform=RandomHorizontalFlip(p=0.5)` and import `from torchvision.transforms import RandomHorizontalFlip`, which would look like this.

```
import torch
from torch.utils.data import Dataset
from torchvision import datasets
from torchvision.transforms import ToTensor, RandomHorizontalFlip
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


training_data = datasets.FashionMNIST(
    root="data",
    train=True,
    download=True,
    transform=RandomHorizontalFlip(0.5)
)

test_data = datasets.FashionMNIST(
    root="data",
    train=False,
    download=True,
    transform=ToTensor()
)
```

Comment: Thanks! but this example work for their datasets, I mean in case I create my own one. The workaround that I can think is creating 2 datasets classes.. but it's not so elegant solution.